# Find the first parent element but not before root parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML structure lik3

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Other elements</div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li class='base-parent parent'>
              <div>Base Parent DEFINED</div>
              <ul>
                <li class="parent parent-level-1">
                  <div class="child">Inner Parent Level 1</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="parent parent-level-2">
                      <div class="child">Inner Parent Level 2</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li class="parent parent-level-3">
                          <div class="child">Innermost child 1</div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="parent parent-level-3">
                          <div class="child">Innermost child 2</div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Though I can find the closest parent LI of div.child, I need to know how I can find the first parent LI element of class div.child under li.base-parent excluding base-parent.

Comment: Could you add an HTML comment, or some text, in that code explicitly showing which element you need to find, and from where your traversal starts?

Comment: what have you tried till now? we need to see the code to figure out what u are trying to achieve

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/ check if this solves your problem

Comment: .closest( selector ) can solve my problem though. However, I simply want the closest parent LI element of div.child class but in any case I do not want to traverse up the DOM element before li.base-parent. In other words, I would like the combination of closest() and parentsUntil()

Comment: @Himal, what's wrong with the solution I have provided?

Comment: @Himal, did you check my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$('.child').parents('li.parent:not(.base-parent)').last();
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2qBE/).

Comment: Hi BenM, I really appreciate the solution. I simply want to traverse until the immediate parent LI up the DOM tree from the bottom. I was just wondering whether it would be possible to find the bottom up approach just in case.

Comment: This is bottom-up? It starts with the first `li.parent` parent of `.child` and works up.

Comment: Thanks again BenM. That works absolutely well... I should have asked as to find immediate first parent LI from my div.child class up the DOM tree not going further above li.base-parent

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an unreasonable amount of divs. Have you heard of ids?

Then the task is a lot simpler.

i.e.

```
$('#myide').whatever();
```

Comment: This is not really offering a solution to the problem. Besides that, ids are the way to make your code not reusable since you can only have one per page